# Unit of velocity.dy property in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, physics

I was just wondering what the units are for the velocity of a physics body in sprite kit.

In my app I have a gravity of (0,-5), however when I print the velocity.dy of a downward moving sprite it jumps to -750 very quickly (the sprite has only moved halfway down iPhone 5s screen). What unit is this measured in? Also the gravity of (0,-5) means -5m/s^2 right?

Comment: I definitely can reproduce this, and others have made similar comments. The best explanation I've found is in this (unaccepted) answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20036658/97337. SK Gravity does not appear to actually behave the way the docs say it does. It is significantly different from a -9.8N force applied every frame.

Comment: That explanation makes a lot of sense! Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

Sprite Kit uses the International System of Units, also known as SI

So it's probably m/s (meters per second)

Comment: Thats what I thought at first too. But then why would the y velocity drop from 0 to -750 in less than 4 seconds, with an acceleration of only -5? Am I interpreting velocity.dy wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure it's something like 100 pt/s^2. At least, that's how UIKit Dynamics works.