# How to make a sprite jump to a specific height with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, sprite-kit

I am trying to use applyImpulse to make a sprite jump to a specific height. In the example code below, the dynamic black circle jumps to the same height as the static red circle, but it only works with a kludge.

If my physics is right, the required initial vertical momentum to launch a projectile to height Y is given by mass * sqrt(2 * gravity * Y). Yet this formula results in the black circle moving very little.

Through trial and error, I have discovered that I can make the red circle jump more or less accurately by multiplying the vertical component of the impulse vector by 12.3, as illustrated in the code below.

This seems completely arbitrary and is driving me crazy. I am obviously doing something wrong. What's the right way to do this?

Here's what I think is the relevant bit of code:

```
let dy = mass * sqrt( 
    2 * -self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy 
    * (fixedCircle.position.y-jumpingCircle.position.y)) 
    * 12.3

jumpingCircle.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, CGFloat(dy)))
```

Here's the GameScene.swift class in its entirety, should you wish to copy and paste...

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var jumpingCircle = SKShapeNode()
var fixedCircle = SKShapeNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.scaleMode = .AspectFit

    // Create an exterior physical boundary
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:self.frame)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5);


    // Create the jumping circle
    jumpingCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    jumpingCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 100,y: 0)
    jumpingCircle.strokeColor = .blackColor()
    jumpingCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    jumpingCircle.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    self.addChild(jumpingCircle)


    // Create the fixed circle
    fixedCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    fixedCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 100,y: 384)
    fixedCircle.strokeColor = .redColor()
    self.addChild(fixedCircle)

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    // to reach certain height, initial y velocity should by sqrt(2 * gravity * Y)
    // momentum required to reach this velocity is mass * velocity
    // therefore, vertical impulse should be given by mass * sqrt(2 * gravity * Y)

    if let mass = jumpingCircle.physicsBody?.mass{
        // calculate vertical impulse

        // this formula "should work" but does not
        // let dy = mass * sqrt(2 * -self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy * (fixedCircle.position.y-jumpingCircle.position.y))

        // this formula "works", but has the arbitrary multiplier
        let dy = mass * sqrt(2 * -self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy * (fixedCircle.position.y-jumpingCircle.position.y)) * 12.3

        // apply the Impulse
        jumpingCircle.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, CGFloat(dy)))
     }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your equation looks okay to me. Impulse is Mass * Change in Velocity. Since you want to be going from zero to velocity (v), then your Impulse would be  i = (m * sqrt(2(9.81)(y2-y1))) as long as you're working only with the y axis. Edit: Can't use a negative inside a square root.

Comment: @Owatch: The gravity vector itself is negative, so in the dy formula the sqrt is a positive. And I'm glad the equation looks okay. But it still doesn't work. Red circle jumps just a tiny bit.

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit's built in gravity?
Edit: Okay, I see

Comment: Yes, on line 6 or so of the code example: self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5).

Comment: Why is gravity -5, although I suppose it should not matter given you continue to use that constant. Even if you accidentally had it using -9.81 somewhere, it would just make it go too high. (Or inversely, too low if you had the object use -5 and real gravity be -9.81)

Comment: Because it was a nice round number I could use for testing, and to determine if the gravity vector was part of the problem. It's not. You can run the code above, change the world gravity to -9.8 or whatever, and get the exact same behavior and results. You still need the 12.3 multiplier. Actually, the fact that the formula works regardless of a) the world gravity, or b) the mass of the object, is my biggest clue that the basic physics formula is correct. But it's as if there's a 12.3 unit-to-pixel ratio that has to be accounted for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out.

SpriteKit apparently has an undocumented pixel-to-"meter" ratio of 150.

I discovered this when I realized the mass SpriteKit was automatically calculating for my circles was *not* 50*pi*r^2 as it should be. I worked backward from mass to calculate the radius SpriteKit was using, and it was 7500, which happens to be 50*150.

And 12.3? It just happens to be (approximately) the square root of 150.

So to make these physics simulations work, you have to consider this ratio. I'm calling it "pixel to unit" (PTU) because it has nothing to do with meters in spite of Apple's insistence that SpriteKit uses SI units. But because it's undocumented it seems possible to change, so I'm kicking off my simulation using the following line of code to determine the true PTU:

```
let ptu = 1.0 / sqrt(SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width:1,height:1)).mass)
```

This is an expensive operation, so it should only be called once. I'm calling it when setting up the initial Scene.

My impulse calculation is now as follows:

```
let dy = mass * sqrt(2 
    * -self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy 
    * (fixedCircle.position.y-jumpingCircle.position.y 
    * ptu))
```

And now the black circle jumps to perfect alignment with the red circle and I can go back to sleeping at night.

Comment: is it 150 pixels or points? i need a retina an non-retina constant, thanks.

Comment: This is freaking amazing!! Thank you!!!! I'm sure this took a lot of work. Here is ptu in whatever the latest version of things are: let  ptu = 1.0 / sqrt(SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)).mass)

Comment: how can we do this for horizontal movement? I find that on smaller screens the player moves much faster with the same velocity. However the horizontal gravity is zero, rendering this calculation useless.

Comment: Are the parenthesis accurate in this equation? it seems odd to multiply the ptu only on the jumpingCircle position instead of the difference of the two.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of applyImpulse use velocity. Velocity will be more specific. 

`jumpingCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(jumpingCircle.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 300.0f);`

Code not tested.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem the right way. applyForce() will "push" the circle up, accellerating it because the force is constant for a duration of time. I need to simulate jumping, vertically, against a gravitational pull. That's exactly what applyImpulse is supposed to do (and, in fact, does -- just with this odd kludge to make it work correctly.)