# Mysterious factor of 150 on SpriteKit's Physics. Gravity and Forces

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I wanted an object to float on the screen, resisting gravity, not moving at all.

This is the gravity setting of the view.

```
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 5.0)
```

it's set to **5m/s^2** upwards. So object gets accelerated by **5m** upwards per second.

Mass of the object is set to **1.0kg**

```
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 1.0
```

I applied a force to the object so it can resist the gravity. So I did the following.

```
func update(delta: TimeInterval) {
    ...

    let force = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0)
    self.physicsBody?.applyForce(force)
}
```

I applied **-5N** because I thought the gravitational force applied to the object is **1kg * 5m/s^2 = 5N**. Applying **-5N** will make the object gets accelerated by **-5m/s^2**, floating on the screen as a result with the gravity.

But it did not work. Instead I had to do this.

```
    let force = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0 * 150.0)
```

**-5** multiplied by **150** is **-750**. So, where does this **150** come from? Why do I have to apply **-750N** instead of **-5N** to make the object resist gravity?

I also tested out different masses and forces on different gravity settings.

```
self.physicsBody?.mass = 2.0
let force = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0 * 150.0 * 2)
```

---

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 15.0)
self.physicsBody?.mass = 2.0
let force = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -15.0 * 150.0 * 2)
```

and they all worked find. F=ma.

Question is the mysterious factor of **150**. Where the hell does it come form?

Comment: 150 is 150 points to 1 meter, they failed to do the conversion from meters to points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it was all about wrong documentation of Apple.
Here's the truth of 150.

> this seems to be little bit stupid, but applyForce is measured in ((points * kilo) / sec ^ 2), but the gravity acceleration is in Newtons ((kilo * meter)/ sec ^ 2) (despite the fact it's described as meters per second in documentation. Meters per second! Acceleration!). Multiply it by mass and get the force.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868380/5752908

Come on, Apple... It's been out there for 4 years.

Comment: meters per second squared and meters per second are equivalent in this case, you cant specify the amount of seconds used  150 / 1 ^ 2 = 150 ^ 1 ^ 1